# OpenNI2.0 - getting LNK errors trying to build included sample projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, kinect, openni

I'm getting LNK errors trying to build anything from source in Visual Studio 2010.

I've installed OpenNI 2.0, the Kinect SDK, and NiTE. I can run any of the pre-compiled samples, but I can't compile any of them myself.

I tried to make a sample project just copying what SimpleRead had and that won't compile either; I've followed the instructions of adding all the dependencies and stuff for Visual Studio.

Example:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__oniDeviceIsCommandSupported
```

Theres 16 other similar errors.

Comment: Errors like this are why I finally quit C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error.  What I noticed is that I was using 64bit libraries while trying to build a 32bit application (I just wasn't paying attention).  once I pointed my project to the correct Lib files (32-bit) everything built without errors.  I hope that helps.